# Meaning of "one bit glinting more than the rest"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> People liked the idea of our being together,
>   leaving the city for the country. So many people visited, and the fireplace made all of them
>   want to tell amazing stories; the child who happened to be standing on the right corner
>   when the door of the ice cream truck came open and hundreds of popsicles crashed out;
>   the man standing on the beach, sand sparkling in the sun, **one bit glinting more than the
>   rest**, stooping to find a diamond ring. Did they talk about amazing things because they
>   thought we'd turn into one of them?

Dose it refer to diamond and mean: finding the diamond is better than finding anything else.

This context is from a short story named: snow by Ann Beattie

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct that the passage means, "one bit [of the sand] was glinting (sparkling) more than the rest [of the sand]", and of course that bit was the diamond, not sand.

But the specific phrase, "one bit glinting more than the rest", is just a literal description of the way the event happened. The story, taken as a whole, is about the extra meaning given to stories and events in people's lives, but the phrase itself does not carry any special metaphorical significance beyond just telling what happened when a sparkly diamond ring was found at the beach.